# Firefox and DRM

Tags: firefox, drm, fennec

I'm having problems with DRM (forward lock) protected audio files in Firefox. I the following post I have commented some issues related to DRM and mp4 files:

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=2788283

But I'm wondering if Firefox has a built-in DRM engine, since I don't observe that the  protected files are encrypted with the AES-128 algorithm and turn into a dcf or fl file. If I open the downloaded files the specific DRM headers:

--boundary-1
Content-Type:audio/aac
Content-Transfer-Encoding:binary

are visible. In Chrome the file has a dcf extension and has following headers:
audio FWLK(.....

I think that in Chrome the file gets converted into a specific forward lock file but in Firefox this process doesn't happen.

Does Firefox have a DRM engine?

Many thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: for future readers , I recently wrote a post for drm ( aameer.github.io/articles/digital-rights-management-multi-drm/ ) and it also includes a section of current state of drm and I have covered widevine which is supported by firefox 47+ on windows and mac

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't have a built-in DRM engine, nor does any other open-source browser.

Comment: Does Google Chrome implement DRM support only in mobile versions? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Chrome certainly has some DRM support on ChromeBooks too.  They don't (yet) have support for it on desktop, but they're clearly working on it.

Answer (score 0):

[Mozilla](https://blog.mozilla.org/blog/2014/05/14/drm-and-the-challenge-of-serving-users/) is [now](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/05/reconciling-mozillas-mission-and-w3c-eme/) [unfortunately](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2014/05/mozilla-and-drm) [planning](http://www.theguardian.com/technology/2014/may/14/firefox-closed-source-drm-video-browser-cory-doctorow) to have DRM support in Firefox. It will be an open source sandbox around a binary blob from Adobe.